# What To Do Failed Compiling?

Tags: node.js, typescript, fork, truffle, npm-start

I am getting an error while running the command `npm start`. The file is created in PancakeSwap Frontend and I've been trying to fix this for a while, thanks for your help :)

Here is my App.js code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect  } from "react";
import SimpleStorageContract from "./contracts/SimpleStorage.json";
import getWeb3 from "./getWeb3";
import BlockchainContext from './BlockchainContext.js';

import "./App.css";

function App() {
    const [storageValue, setStorageValue] = useState(undefined);
    const [web3, setWeb3] = useState(undefined);
    const [accounts, setAccounts] = useState([]);
    const [contract, setContract] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        try {
              // Get network provider and web3 instance.
               const web3 = await getWeb3();
        
        //             // Use web3 to get the user's accounts.
                           const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
        
        //                         // Get the contract instance.
                                       const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId();
                                             const deployedNetwork = SimpleStorageContract.networks[networkId];
                                                   const contract  = new web3.eth.Contract(
                                                           SimpleStorageContract.abi,
                                                                   deployedNetwork && deployedNetwork.address,
                                                                         );
        
                                                                               // Set web3, accounts, and contract to the state, and then proceed with an                                                             // example of interacting with the contract's methods.
                 
            setWeb3(web3);
            setAccounts(accounts);
            setContract(contract);;
            
            this.setState({ web3, accounts, contract: instance                       } catch (error) {
                                                                        // Catch any errors for any of the above operations.
                                                                       alert(
                                                                      `Failed to load web3, accounts, or contract. Check console for details.`,
                                                                                                                         );
                                                                                                                               console.error(error);
        
        const init = async() => {
        }
        init();
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
            const load = async () => {
            // Stores a given value, 5 by default.
             await contract.methods.set(5).send({ from: accounts[0] });
        
        //         // Get the value from the contract to prove it worked.
                     const response = await contract.methods.get().call();
        
        //                 // Update state with the result.
                     setStorageValue(response);       
        }
        if(typeof web3 !== 'undefined'
            && typeof account !== 'undefined'
            && typeof contract !== 'undefined'{
            load();
            }
    }, [web3, accounts, contract]);

    if(typeof web3 === 'undefined') {
    return <div>Loading Web3, account, and contract...</div>;
    }

      return (
                <div className="App">
          <BlockchainContext.Provider value={{web3, accounts, contract}}>
                  <h1>Good to Go!</h1>
                  <p>Your Truffle Box is installed and ready.</p>
                  <h2>Smart Contract Example</h2>
                  <p>
                    If your contracts compiled and migrated successfully, below will show
                    a stored value of 5 (by default).
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    Try changing the value stored on <strong>line 42</strong> of App.js.
                  </p>
                  <div>The stored value is: {storageValue}</div>
          </BlockchainContext.Provider>
                </div>
              );

}

export default App;
```

And the error which I am getting is:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/App.js
  Line 17:23:  Parsing error: Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function

  15 |      try {
  16 |            // Get network provider and web3 instance.
> 17 |             const web3 = await getWeb3();
     |                          ^
  18 |      
  19 |      //             // Use web3 to get the user's accounts.
  20 |                         const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
```

Comment: You need to review async-await in js to solve it and also your code looks really not clean and it make stuff complicated to understand there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code provided is pretty messy, but it looks like you are trying to use the `await` keyword in a synchronous function, specifically the function being passed as an argument into `useEffect()`. The `await` keyword can only be used inside [asynchronous functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).
If you can, the easiest solution would be to make the function asynchronous by adding the `async` keyword (demonstrated below).

```
function App() {
    const [storageValue, setStorageValue] = useState(undefined);
    const [web3, setWeb3] = useState(undefined);
    const [accounts, setAccounts] = useState([]);
    const [contract, setContract] = useState([]);

    useEffect(async () => {
```

If that won't work, you could use `.then()` instead (demonstrated below), however this will require more work.

```
function App() {
    const [storageValue, setStorageValue] = useState(undefined);
    const [web3, setWeb3] = useState(undefined);
    const [accounts, setAccounts] = useState([]);
    const [contract, setContract] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        try {
              // Get network provider and web3 instance.
               getWeb3().then(web3=>{
                  // code goes here
               }).catch(err=>{
                  // error handling
               });
```

I also recommend reading a little about async/await if you haven't already. [This MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) is a good place to start.